# How can my gods be explained as abstract life forms?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, gods

My idea for my fantasy world is that magic is a philosophy, and through a process an individual understands that they are a collection of particles that is conscious, and they have the ability to use their conscious choices to alter particles around them.

So, for gods, I am imagining that if individuals focus on certain ideologies, those ideologies begin to manifest into individual consciouses of their own, creating gods. Because they do not have a physical form that they are anchored to, they are able to alter their appearance and manipulate reality much easier.

1.) Does this make any sense or have I really lost it

2.) Is there a more concise way of wording that, or maybe a different way of their being?

Comment: What's the point here? "Because they do not have a physical form that they are anchored to, they are able to alter their appearance and manipulate reality much easier."
Other than that, it's ok in general. Phylosophy, ideology, tricky words, I would not use those, just to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Ideologies like there was a god of Communism? And of Phrenology? And still a god of Existentialism?

Comment: I guess that their consciousness is free form, manifested out of thin air and able to move without a physical form. And ideologies as in things people would pray for. Hope, wellness, destruction, hate, love, trickery, luck.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of this question are meaningless. Unless, of course, the words *philosophy*, *particle*, *conscious*, *ideology*, and even *because*, are to be assigned unusual meanings; in which case, it would be a great help is those meanings were specified, or, even better, appropriate words were used.

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate what I think you're saying. Gods are manifestations of their worshipper's magic, composed of only magic, non-material particles and taking on the principles imposed by the faithful. Their form and abilities derive from their worshippers, but they have become separate entities in their own right. Because they are non-material, they themselves have A.) a greater understanding of the magi-particulate nature of reality that gives entities control of reality, and B.) since they are themselves derived from collective will, their form and abilities are lees concretely defined and therefor easy to manipulate.

- Absolutely. Gods deriving from their worshippers is a common fantasy principle. The explanation is internally consistent with how gods operate. It explains how the god has a new existence as something from their worshippers, but also how they have their own essential identity.This same principle could be applied to any (spirit/god/demon/angel/ghost). It even suggests how a sort of afterlife could manifest from your system (transcending material existence to attain greater spiritual awareness). It's very Luke Skywalker/Yoda/ Midi-chlorians.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy.**

You already did!

Basically what you're describing falls under "calling gods (etc.) into existence through belief (or some other rational act of the will)". I would describe it pretty much as you just did: *an individual (can) focus on a certain ideology, or, presumably, aspects of a grand ideology, and with sufficient concentration said ideology begins to coalesce within the ordinary realm, it manifests into an individual consciousness of its own*.

Easy peasy lemon squeezy!

This, if you weren't aware is the premise behind PTerry's *Hogfather*; and is succinctly described in the manifestation of the [Verruca Gnome](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Verruca_Gnome).